# R function to connect to wireless

Tags: r

I am running a code for a client. Is there a R function / command to connect the computer to the available wireless and type in the passcode automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.

However, you can run any OS command with [`system`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html), so if you have a shell command `foo` which does what you want, you can just do `system("foo")` in `R`.

Answer (score 1):

Most connections to the "outside world" with R are handled through the OS version of system-level 'libcurl' package. There is a package for R called RCurl. The authentication system is described in the variaous pages of:

```
help(package="RCurl") # brings up the index page.
help(getURL, package="RCurl") # has examples of authentication to a server with R code.
```

You should also read:

```
?connections
```